# Pubnub + React native - No banner notification on iOS real device

Tags: iphone, react-native, push-notification, pubnub, react-native-ios

I have integrated Pubnub Javascript sdk-v4 with my react native project.
And have used https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification for react native push notification. In both simulators (android and iOS),  the notification banner is shown when the app is running in the background (even if the app is closed). However, the notification banner isn't displayed when tested on a real device. The notification is only shown in the notification bar (when scrolled from the top of the screen). Any suggestion?

Code segment likes follows.

```
.
.
var PushNotification = require('react-native-push-notification');
var serviceCall = require('../../actions/serviceCall');
import PushController from '../../actions/pushController'
var PubNub = require('pubnub');
.
.

class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ...
            ...

        };
        this.constructor.childContextTypes = {
            theme: React.PropTypes.object,
        }

    }
componentDidMount(){

    var pubnub = new PubNub({
        publishKey : 'pub-c-xxxxxx', 

        subscribeKey : 'sub-c-xxxxxx'


      })
      var notifyListener ={
        message: function(message) {

            console.warn(JSON.stringify(message));
            PushNotification.localNotification({

                message: message.message.text, // (required)

            });

        }
      }
    pubnub.addListener(notifyListener);

    pubnub.subscribe({
        channels: ['Channel-xxxxxxx']
        });
    }

return (
            <Container>
                    <View theme={theme}>
                    <PushController/>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    </View>
            </Container>
        )
}
```

Comment: Can you update your code with the full code from the same file?

Comment: @CraigConover, Nice to here from you. I updated the code segment. I'm unable to put the all code file here. This is the flow of the code file and this is the first page of navigation. (main page after user login).

Comment: Hi @CraigConover, any update?

Comment: We need more details. Can you submit complete zipped project with repro steps and data to support@pubnub.com? We can post the answer back here when resolved.

Comment: It was a problem with way how I integrate the notification method with Pubnub. Then I tried this (https://www.pubnub.com/docs/react-native-javascript/mobile-gateway) and It was success. Thanks for the help @CraigConover .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to change the method of integration and this link was success.

Link: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/react-native-javascript/mobile-gateway

Comment: can you upload updated working code? I am running into the same issue and the documentation is a bit confusing